# Remapping keys in iterm2

Tags: iterm

I'm trying to remap some of the default key combinations in iTerm2, and would like to understand what is going on when I bind keys to "Send Hex Codes".

A previous post helped me get started with remapping the ctrl-a and ctrl-e key combos to cmd-left and cmd-right, respectively, but I would like to remap other key combos as well. ([Link to previous Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205157/iterm2-how-to-get-jump-to-beginning-end-of-line-in-bash-shell/10485061#10485061)).

I have a vague understanding that there are hex codes involved, but I am at a point where I can't figure out where to go next to understand what's going on or what to do.

Comment: Has nothing to do with bash. Removed tag.

Answer (score 21):

Those hex codes are just sequences of bytes. For example mapping a key combination to `0x66 0x6f 0x6f` would make it insert `foo`. `0xc3 0xa4` would insert ä if you use UTF-8. `0x1b 0x1b 0x5b 0x43` means `escape escape [ C`.

Some sequences of bytes like [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) and even single bytes like ASCII control characters have special meanings in terminals.

To make ⌘← and ⌘→ go to the beginning and end of line, you can assign them to 0x01 (^A in caret notation) and 0x05 (^E in caret notation):

- ⌘←: Send Hex Codes: 0x01
- ⌘→: Send Hex Codes: 0x05

You can make ⌥⌦ delete a word forward by assigning it to `\ed`:

- ⌥⌦: Send ^[ d

Changing ⌥← and ⌥→ to `\eb` and `\ef` in iTerm's preferences would also change them in programs that don't support readline or emacs-style keybindings. Another option is to add this to [~/.inputrc](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html):

```
"\e\e[D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
```

You can run `read` and press key combinations to see what characters they insert. For example ⌥← inserts `^[^[[D` by default, where `^[` is escape in [caret notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation).

See also http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/wiki/Keybindings.

Comment: Thanks. I run into this answer when looking up a solution for my question [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144481/sending-controlalt-char-to-terminal-in-iterm2). How  can I look up the hex code for a specific key combination? (in my case I am interested in the combinations `Ctrl+Alt+<char>` with `<char>` being `i`, `j`, `k`, `l` and `u`)

Answer (score 9):

I'd suggest to install [Key Codes](http://manytricks.com/keycodes/) ($0) by Many Tricks and find out the shortcuts for yourself.

For instance if you want to remap the default shortcut for (forward) deleting a charcter – which is Ctrl-D (`⌃D`) – to be as simple as pressing the forward delete key (`⌦`), you would…

1. Open the app and press `Ctrl-D`

   [image: Key Codes Example]
2. Back in iTerm 2, add the Unicode shortcut in iTerm > Preferences > Keys

   [image: iTerm Send Hex Codes]

*Note: Don't copy and paste it, just type out the Unicode without spaces.*

Comment: The action's value you input, should be `0x4`, not `4/0x4`

Answer (score 3):

The best way that I found was either with sending keycodes (as described by @pattulus or using vim key bindings.

**Note on key codes:** Actually you cannot make it work by sending the unicode string as described above, you need to send both the modifier and the key to gether in case of <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> you need to send this as code: `0x840101 0x4` where `0x840101` is the control key modifier and can be obtained through [Key Code](http://manytricks.com/keycodes/).

**Note on sending as vim sequence**:
As described in iTerm2 [documentation](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-one-page.html), you can send a key code in vim-bindings format such as `\<C-d>` for sending <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (note that `\` is important).

I personally prefer vim key binding because it's more readable and later you will understand what you have done.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).

Within this tool you can create key custom mappings that are specific to applications. It comes with some tools to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

`Preferences` → `Profile` → `Keys` add the following shortcuts:

---

<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> Send Escape Sequence Esc+ b

<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> Send Escape Sequence Esc+ f

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> Send Escape Sequence Esc+ [H

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> Send Escape Sequence Esc+ [F

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>←Delete</kbd> Send Hex Code 0x18 0x7f (add `bindkey "^X\\x7f" backward-kill-line` to `.zshrc`)

<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>←Delete</kbd> Send Hex Code 0x1B 0x08

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Del→</kbd> Send Hex Code 0x0b

<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>Del→</kbd> Send Escape Sequence d