# Sending Control+Alt+ <char> to terminal in iTerm2

Tags: keyboard, iterm, shortcut

When I press `Control + Command + i` I would like iTerm2 to send the shortcut as `C-M-i` (i.e. `ctrl`+`alt`+`i`) to my terminal.

I have

How can I do that?

I have tried with the following with no luck:
[image]

Any thoughts on how to get this to work?

### Update:

I read the following [here](http://jkpl.lepovirta.org/how-do-i/ctrl-meta-space-in-iterm2.html):

> ```
> To have iTerm2 send "C-M-Space" to the terminal:
> 1) Open: Preferences > Profiles > some session you wish to edit > Keys.
> 2) Add a new key binding by pressing the "+" button.
> 3) Select the "Keyboard Shortcut" field, and press ctrl + option + space.
> 4) Select "Send Hex Code" in the "Action" list.
> 5) Type "0x1b 0x00" to the field below the list.
> 6) Click OK and close the preferences window.
> ```

I wonder if I can follow the same approach for my problem. How do I find out which Hex Code I need to send for `Control+Command+i`?

### Update 2

After reading [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/445379/how-can-i-remap-controle-to-escapecontrole-in-iterm2), I installed `Key Codes` and found the following info for `Control + Command + i`. What specifically am I supposed to enter as a `hex code`in iTerm2 for this to work?

[image]

Comment: How exactly do you expect to send the command key to the terminal?

Comment: Thanks @0942v8653 I would like to send it as `Alt`

Answer (score 3):

I finally sorted out the various issues to come up with a solution.  The problem seems to be that if the `Control key` is part of the keyboard shortcut  then no other modifier keys that are also pressed will change the code that is sent by that keypress.  If `Control + i` produces the `^i` (`tab`) character then adding more modifiers to the shortcut will still produce the same `^i` code, at least when using `iTerm2`.  This may be occurring at the OSX level or perhaps at the Unix level where a `termcap` table handles the translation of "terminal keys" to "output codes." It can be observed with `iTerm2` by using `"cat -v"` or `"vis -o"` to see the output being generated and is also seen when using `Key Codes` (without `iTerm2` running) which makes OSX the more likely culprit. That conclusion is supported by noting that the general user is not able to redefine certain keyboard shortcuts (without difficulty) that are reserved for basic OSX functions (such as `Command-Tab` for program switching).

It is possible to programmatically differentiate any set of modifiers pressed with a character key but those modifier flags are accessible programmatically within OSX and by a totally unique set of codes for every different set of keys pressed. To witness this, use `Key Codes` and while holding the `Control` key and pressing a character key and then doing the same while pressing additional modifier keys at the same time, note that it is always the same character code that is produced. Yet `Key Codes` has access to the various keys being held and is able to display them to us in the "modifier" field that it reveals. And, if `iTerm2` could only see the standard codes produced from various key presses and not also see the modifier flags then `iTerm2` itself wouldn’t be able to define the range of shortcut keys that it is actually able to define.  On the other hand, after identifying each set differently modified keys in a unique manner, `iTerm2` appears to pass it’s generated codes to OSX where they are handled in the same way as if they’d been keyed on a keyboard, resulting in identical output for groups distinguishable keystrokes.  So, for example, `iTerm2` may pass the unique `Control + Alt + i` determined code(s) out for the use of `tmux` but OSX takes them and tosses out a few details before delivery, making the code appear to be just `^i` when it finally arrives for `tmux` to handle. The shortcut binding in `tmux` expects to receive the code we thought we were sending but along the way OSX has removed the information about the `Alt (Meta)` key, the same as it would do if the keyboard shortcut had been typed on a keyboard.

The solution is to find a key combination that won’t be used for something else and that can be transmitted without being changed to another key combination that you do want to use. That’s where `Key Codes` is useful since it let's you test many key  combinations and find what the key presses are translated to be "unique enough."  Here’s the process I used to make it work for me:

**Goal: Running `tmux` in `iTerm2`, I want to be able to press `Command-Control-i` and have `tmux` execute the "`select-pane -U`"command.**

- Choose an esoteric key press that you won’t be using. Consider a multi-key sequence with the `tmux` escape character followed by another unusual key press making it much less likely to be needed.  I’m choosing to send the standard tmux escape character (`0x02 = ^b`) followed by the ansi code sequence for `F1` (`0x1b 0x4f 0x50`).  Good keys to look at are the less used characters generated on a Mac by holding down `Alt` (`Option`) and `Shift` with another character key.
- Within iTerm2 open Preferences and define the Command+Control+i shortcut in either the global key shortcuts or as a keyboard shortcut for a specific profile.

  - Press the `+` button to add a new shortcut.
  - Click in the Keyboard Shortcut field and hold down the `Command` and `Control` keys while you press the "`i`" key.
  - Use the mouse to select "`Send Hex Code`" in the `Action` drop-down. (Trying to use `Tab` to leave the Shortcut field will change the value for the shortcut.)
  - Type the string "`0x02 0x1b 0x4f 0x50`" (without the quotes and assuming that you are using the default `tmux` escape character, `^b = 0x02`).
  - Press the `OK` button to commit your shortcut. Close `Preferences`.
- Within `iTerm2`, invoke a `tmux` session and define the key binding for the codes `iTerm2` will send.

  - Invoke tmux as you normally would.
  - In the `tmux` window type the command: "`tmux bind-key F1 select-pane -U`" (without the quotes.)

Test it by splitting your `tmux` window into several appropriate panes and try using `Command+Control+i` to move through panes vertically. If successful, you'll probably want to record your key-binding with the start-up bindings invoked by `tmux` on startup.

This method worked fine for me and should work well unless you have somehow used all the possible keyboard combinations for other uses.  Methods like this one combined with practice and experience guessing the inner workings of a system should can help work around situations like this one that may feel foreign and overwhelming. Some parts of the above explanation are reasonable guesses as to what is occurring or that may assign blame to the wrong process but I hope that it’s helpful as a guide to how problems like this can be approached with less than a complete understanding of the whole system.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method to send key-combinations to terminal is to activate +Esc is Key setting.

iTerm2 > Preferences > Profile > Keys > change "option key acts" from normal to +Esc

Comment: This is simple and works. It should be the accepted answer here.

Answer (score 1):

(The theory is in the following 3 paragraphs and the best guess answer is developed in the remainder of this long winded explanation. The spoiler is our educated guess of `0x89` as the answer to the given question. If not then you'll probably need to read much of the rest and do some searching on your own to see exactly what you should send and how. I do hope this helps.)

To sort this out the first thing is to realize that `C-M-i` is not the same as `Control + Command + I` except when (in a specific context such as an OS or a program) the `Command` key is set to be the `Meta` key. In iTerm the choices for the `Meta` key are one or the other of the Option (Alt) keys. In iTerm one can't speak of the Command key as the Meta key although it's possible to capture the Command key press by defining it as an `iTerm` keyboard shortcut. So what does it mean in iTerm to press `Control + Command + i`? It's not defined; it sends no visible or invisible characters at all. (This is best seen by invoking `cat -v`, `vis -o` or another program that will visibly display invisible codes and trying various keystrokes.)\

But the idea of pressing `C-M-i` is somewhat defined and often including the `Meta` key with another key combination is equivalent to pressing the `ESCape` key followed by the same key combination. That appears to be what you were trying to do by setting a key to output the escape sequence: `ESC + ^i`. If that didn't work then we need to know what string of characters/bytes is actually wanted by whatever program you are trying to control. Following the example you pointed to I created a hex sequence of `0x1B 0x09` which produced the same output as your ESC sequence. (Hex `1B` or `0x1B` = Binary `000110111` = Octal `033` or \033 = Decimal `27`…value of `27` **not** `2` followed by `7`; after a while these particular numbers all start to mean `ESCape` character when one sees them.)

Now, `Key Codes` was a good try being the same sort of idea as using `cat` or `vis` to visualize the characters that get sent. The problem is that `Key Codes` is not running within `iTerm` but is running within `OS X.` One could say the `Command` key is `OS X's` `Meta` key but that train of thought isn't useful since `OS X` defines the function of its `Meta` key quite differently from how `iTerm` defines its `Meta` key. If you go into `Key Codes` and try pressing `Control + i` with and without the `Command` key you'll see that the difference is in the resulting modifiers; but the modifiers are internal flags within `OS X` that `OS X` creates by examining what keys are pressed. The actual output code is closest to the Unicode character shown (`0x09`) and you'll see that both with and without the `Command` key you receive the same character. But that's illusory anyway since what actually happens is that `OS X` gets the Key Code and the Modifers values and interprets those codes as it wants. `Control + i` comes closest to "sending" a `^i` but add the `Command` key and, if the `Finder` is the receiving the results, you get one of the various `Get Info` commands; another program may interpret it as it likes. It's turtles on turtles on turtles all the way down, i.e., what you begin with may end up doing many different things depending on what is re-interpreting what, and so on.

Now I have to try to give you an answer that will work for you, but the preceding was necessary to show why I can't say for sure. But I can make an educated guess. First, the context is `iTerm` and I assume you are running a program in iTerm that does something in response to what is said to be `C-M-i.` If, in `iTerm` I set one Option/Alt key to be the Meta key and then press that key with the `^i` keys we will expect that we will get what we want to happen to happen. So let's find out what gets sent by doing that. If you use `Key Caps` it won't say anything different since you're back outside of `iTerm.` But when I use the `cat -v` command which does it's best to make the invisible visible on the screen and press `C-M-i,` then along with a strange diamond shape character I get the string `M-^i` which seems to be a way to say `M-C-i`. That looks good.

Now I get out of the `cat` program and go to the `vis -o` program which will try to give me some octal values for some of the invisible characters. Now pressing `C-M-i` gives me an octal value (after pressing return) of `\211` as well as that funny diamond. (Octal `211` or `\211` = Binary `10001001` = Hex `89` or `0x89;` which is encouraging since when I earlier turned on the `Meta` key in `iTerm` it gave me a warning a that `Meta` was usually used on older systems and new systems generally use the `+ESC` code sequence…back to where you started! I also have seen that what the `Meta` key often did was to output the ASCII 7-bit printable character with its high-order bit (leftmost bit usually set to zero) set to 1. If you strip the leftmost 1 from the binary coding of what we received you're left with a `1001` binary = Decimal 9! `9` is the character that pressing `^i` "sends out." That looks good.

Just to go full circle and check it out further I can go back to `iTerm,` make sure I've turned off my `Meta` key options (just in case) and define a new keyboard shortcut to some key that sends a `0x89` (Hex `89`). Then open a new window so that the changes are active and press the key you assigned the `0x89` with `vis -o` running to interpret your characters. Out comes the same funny diamond shape and the octal string `\211`. So it appears we have set up a shortcut key to produce `C-M-i` to the best of what we know.

Whether that key will do what you want depends on whether the program that wants that keyboard code handles what we gave it. Not knowing more this is a best educated guess. If it fails then it's necessary to delve further into the end program that is being controlled [I'd venture `Emacs` but, *hey*, I use `vi` so what do I know ;-] Hopefully some of the techniques and ideas presented here would help you determine how to send the correct codes once you found them. I hope that this works for you. Note that without all the fuss you can get a pretty good idea that it will or won't work by turning on a `Meta` key in `iTerm` and pressing `C-M-i` to see if that works; if so then proceed to define your shortcut key.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zhora. This is extremely helpful, although unfortunately `0X89` didn't do it. The receiving program is actually `tmux` where I have `.tmux.conf` listening to `bind-key -n C-M-i select-pane -U` (i.e. the shortcut `C-M-i` is supposed to call `select-pane -U`. I am able to do this get this to work if I set it to `M-i` (and ask iTerm to send the appropiate Esc+i, but not with `C-M-i`.

Comment: To be clear, yes I am running Tmux on the shell, even though iTerm technically itself relies on Tmux. This shouldn't matter. I have been doing this for years. I do this because (1) I don't like relying exclusively relying on `iTerm2` for multiplexing, and because (2) this allows me to detach from remote sessions.

Comment: I once wrote up a brief for small claims court and the rigid deadline for filing prevented me from sleeping for 3 days and nights; the result was an absolute mess to say the least. As I look back at your question and my answer I’m reminded of that experience (but to a lesser degree by far). In rereading it I think I may have confused and switched around parts of the question with parts of my intended solution.  I do hope it helped somewhat and I think my newer answer will clarify things and provide a definite solution.